# ¿Es posible escribir un archivos de un servidor externo en un FS hadoop sin el envio local?

Tags: hadoop

Tengo un servidor que genera archivos y estos se envían vía SFTP a otros servidores, hay un nuevo sistema que hace uso de cloudera y tiene un FS hadoop, envío archivos de manera local al nuevo servidor y los cargo con HDFS dfs -put sin problema, como podría cargar los archivos desde el servidor externo (distinto del clúster de cloudera), trate sin éxito de la siguiente manera:

```
cat a.txt |  ssh user@IP 'hdfs dfs -put hdfs://hostname.com:8020/RUTA/DAT/'

ssh user@IP 'hdfs dfs -put /home/a.txt hdfs://hostname.com:8020/RUTA/DAT/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola prueba lo siguiente

```
cat test.txt | ssh username@masternode "hadoop dfs -put - hadoopFoldername/test.txt"
```

O con la siguiente opcion:

```
tar cf - . | ssh remote "(cd /destination && tar xvf -)"
```

Este ultimo dejara en formato tar.

Recuerda que en muchos casos, HDFS tiene seguridad con kerberos, y realmente sera un dolor de cabeza para acceder.

Espero que tengas suerte!